# Problem for template class<class_name> that has bitset as argument

Tags: c++, objective-c++

I want to write a class in C++ in which one of the parameter is a `bitset<size>`.
I want to give the facility to vary this "size" for any object of that class but should be constant for that object.

If I make a variable `const int size;` and initialize it in the constructor, then it does not compile because to writiting `bitset<size>` would require `size` to be static which would make it same for all objects of the class.

Is there any other method than making a class template and passing the size as `classname<size>`?

thanks but.. but this makes this Foo class objects whenever used as composition (object as data member)... would it be necessary to again make that class template. I made a class and Passed a (#define BIT_SIZE 16 to Foo bits;) it is giving compile errors undefined reference to Foo<16>::Foo(). where Foo() is the constructor. I thought it should work because that is also compile time. and i just wanted to make only size BIT_SIZE bits. should i make my "next level" class template ?? it can be that these errors were because of other mistakes. but i checked that again and again.

---

yes sir i have implemented that and but included the header files and not cpp files .......... when i changed these to cpp files ... multiple declaration error came. i am working on linux ubuntu .. when i took these files to dev_cpp in windows that worked . may be because compiler did that automatically what i need to do. so what is that i need to do.

Comment: What's all this conversation in your question? To whom are you replying?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, there is no other method, because the code for actual instantiation for `bitset<N>` is generated at compile time, so you have no possibility to delay providing its size until runtime. You have to use the non-type template parameter.

If it was possible, the creators of standard C++ library would have done this and it would be possible to provide the size for `bitset` at runtime, right?

Using another bit set implementation is an option.

Answer (score 2):

Template parameter should be compile time constant; the compiler will generate different classes for different size parameters. If you want to use single bitset class for various possible sizes then use, for instance,  Boost dynamic_bitset:

http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_47_0/libs/dynamic_bitset/dynamic_bitset.html

and pass the bitset size as constructor parameter

Answer (score 1):

To use the `bitset` member, you have to make `size` a template parameter and use that in the member:

```
template <size_t N>
class Foo
{
  std::bitset<N> thebitset;

public:
  Foo() /* ... */
};
```

Then to use it, say `Foo<12> x;`.

In view of your question for alternatives, you could use a runtime-dynamic array instead of a static one:

```
class Bar
{
  std::vector<unsigned char> thedata;

public:
  explicit Bar(size_t n) : thedata(n, 0) { }

  inline unsigned char & operator[](size_t i) { return thedata[i]; }
  inline const unsigned char & operator[](size_t i) const { return thedata[i]; }
};
```

Comment: thanks but.. it is ok to use it . but this makes this Foo class objects whenever used as composition (object as data member)... would it be necessary to again make that class template. I made a class and Passed a (#define BIT_SIZE 16 to Foo<BIT_SIZE> bits;) it is giving compile errors undefined reference to Foo<16>::Foo(). where Foo() is the constructor. I thought it should work because that is also compile time. and i just wanted to make only size BIT_SIZE bits. should i make my "next level" class template ?? it can be that these errors were because of other mistakes. but i checked that

Comment: i even  gave Default value to BITS_SIZE in Foo<int size = BITS_SIZE>

Comment: "undefined refrence" is not a compile time error, it's a linker error. Did you implement the constructor?

Comment: yes sir i have implemented that and but included the header files and not cpp files .......... when i changed these to cpp files ... multiple declaration error came. i am working on linux ubuntu .. when i took these files to dev_cpp in windows that worked . may be because compiler did that automatically what i need to do. so what is that i need to do.